# Get value from list of dictionnary in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list of dictionaries, I would like to get the `user_quota` for each project and sum it up.

Here is an example.

For the project blue, I would like to get all the user_quota and sum them up, so I will have a total of 3G for the blue project and 5G for the red project.

```yaml
project_dictionnary:
  project_blue:
    project_code: blue
    project_users:
      - user_name: Jhon
        user_quota: 1G
      - user_name: Peter
        user_quota: 2G

  project_red:
    project_code: red
    project_users:
      - user_name: Nelly
        user_quota: 3G
      - user_name: Kelly
        user_quota: 2G
```

I tried this but it did not give the expected result:

```yaml
- name: "Get user_quota"
  set_fact:
    total: "{{ total|default(0)|int + item[:-1]|int }}"
  loop: "{{ project_dictionnary | json_query('.*.project_users[*].user_quota') }}"

- name: "the user quota is:"
  debug: var=total
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of the projects and quotas

```yaml
  pq: "{{ project_dictionnary|dict2items|json_query(pq_query)|items2dict }}"
  pq_query: '[].{key: key, value: value.project_users[].user_quota}'
```

gives

```yaml
  pq:
    project_blue: [1G, 2G]
    project_red: [3G, 2G]
```

Sum the quotas

```yaml
  pq_sum: "{{ dict(pq.keys()|
                   zip(pq.values()|
                       map('map', 'replace', 'G', '')|
                       map('map', 'int')|map('sum'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  pq_sum:
    project_blue: 3
    project_red: 5
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    project_dictionnary:
      project_blue:
        project_code: blue
        project_users:
          - user_name: Jhon
            user_quota: 1G
          - user_name: Peter
            user_quota: 2G
      project_red:
        project_code: red
        project_users:
          - user_name: Nelly
            user_quota: 3G
          - user_name: Kelly
            user_quota: 2G

    pq: "{{ project_dictionnary|dict2items|json_query(pq_query)|items2dict }}"
    pq_query: '[].{key: key, value: value.project_users[].user_quota}'

    pq_sum: "{{ dict(pq.keys()|
                     zip(pq.values()|
                         map('map', 'replace', 'G', '')|
                         map('map', 'int')|map('sum'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: pq|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: pq_sum
```

Comment: Thank yo so much for the answer. I got the following error.

`TASK [sftp : Quota display] **************************************************** fatal: [server]: FAILED!   msg: |-
    Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:
    'pq_query' is undefined*************** `

Comment: What i did:

`- name: "Quota display"
  set_fact:
    pq: "{{ project_dictionnary|dict2items|json_query(pq_query)|items2dict }}"
    pq_query: '[].{key: key, value: value.project_users[].user_quota}'

- debug:
    var: pq|to_yaml`
NB: I have my dictionary (project_dictionnary) in an other yml file

Answer (score 0):

Thank yo so much for the answer. I got the following error.

```
TASK [sftp : Quota display] **************************************************** fatal: [server]: FAILED!   msg: |-
    Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:
    'pq_query' is undefined***************
```

What i did:

```yaml
- name: "Quota display"
  set_fact:
    pq: "{{ project_dictionnary|dict2items|json_query(pq_query)|items2dict }}"
    pq_query: '[].{key: key, value: value.project_users[].user_quota}'

- debug:
    var: pq|to_yaml
```

NB: I have my dictionary (project_dictionnary) in an other yml file

Answer (score 0):

Work for me !!

Thanks @Vladimir Botka

```
- name: Get Quota
  set_fact:
    quota: "{{ pq_sum }}"
  vars:
    pq: "{{ project_dictionnary|dict2items|json_query(pq_query)|items2dict }}"
    pq_query: "{{ '[].{key: key, value: value.project_users[].user_quota}' }}"
    pq_sum: "{{ dict(pq.keys()|
                     zip(pq.values()|
                         map('map', 'replace', 'G', '')|
                         map('map', 'int')|map('sum'))) }}"
- debug:
    var: quota
```